# socket.io xhr post error on slow connection (3G mobile network)

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0, socket.io-java-client

While I am testing my real chat application on 3G mobile network (Slow internet connection),
`Socket.io` repeatedly disconnects then reconnects. I have logged the reason. 
it says `"xhr post error"` which raise `"transport error"` then disconnect.

May I know what is the meaning of `"xhr post error"` and why this error appears in slow connection and how to solve the problem?.

I am using [socket.io-client.java](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java) version 0.4.2

Answer (score 2):

I think you should set `transports` at your client to use websockets.

Try this:

```
IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
opts.transports = new String[]{"websocket"};
mSocket = IO.socket(SOCKET_SERVER, opts);
```

**Update**
Also, try to update your client library to 5.1+.

Comment: But by this line u force the server  to use only websocket and stop the other alternatives .

Answer (score 2):

First of all update the dependency to `1.0.0`

```
implementation ('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
 }
```

And create the `option` with `transport`

```
val ioOption = IO.Options().apply {
            query = /*..*/
            reconnection = /*..*/
            transports = arrayOf("websocket")
        }
```

And then create socket connection with that `option`

```
try {
      socket = IO.socket(baseUrl, ioOption)
     } catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
       e.printStackTrace()
     }

 socket.connect()
```

and listen on `EVENT_RECONNECT_ATTEMPT`

```
socket.on(Socket.EVENT_RECONNECT_ATTEMPT) {
            ioOption.transports = arrayOf("polling", "websocket")
}
```

there is no magic under the hood just implement what document told . [Read More](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#With-websocket-transport-only)

NOTE: you can change appropriate `transport` name, here I used **websocket** to be same as document.